# Grid Bag Layout Doesnt displays anything!! JAVA

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

First of all I looked around stackoverflow and I didnt find anything related to my problem.

Im trying to use the GridBagLayout, the first time I tried it it was functioning, but I dont know what I did, that now it doesnt displays anything, do you have any idea of mas happening??

Heres all code:

```
package Instrucciones;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
*
* @author Antonio
*/
public class JDialog1TxArea extends JDialog {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //Contains all objects
    JTextArea instruc;
    JButton ok;

    public JDialog1TxArea(String instrucciones){  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Instrucciones");
        pack();
        setSize(450,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(mainpanel);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mainpanel.add(panel);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        instruc = new JTextArea(instrucciones);
        ok = new JButton("Aceptar");

        panel.add(instruc, c);
        c.gridy++;
        panel.add(ok, c);
        c.gridy++;   
    }  

    public static void main (String args[]){  
        JDialog1TxArea v = new JDialog1TxArea("Conalep");      
    }  
}
```

The console doesnt have any exception.

Comment: Why are you calling pack(), if there's nothing to pack yet?

Answer (score 3):

Move `setVisible` to the last line in the constructor

```
public JDialog1TxArea(String instrucciones) {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Instrucciones");
    // From here
    //pack();
    //setSize(450, 300);
    //setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //setVisible(true);

    JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(mainpanel);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    mainpanel.add(panel);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

    instruc = new JTextArea(instrucciones);
    ok = new JButton("Aceptar");

    panel.add(instruc, c);
    c.gridy++;
    panel.add(ok, c);
    c.gridy++;

    // To here
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

I'd like to disencourage you from extending from top level containers like `JDialog` and instead design your UI's using `JPanel` as your base container.  You can then add these to what ever top level container you want, even, in your case, using something like `JOptionPane`.  See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

You may also want to have a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), as your `JTextArea` will benefit from it

Comment: Man thanks thanks answering, this is one of the best answers I had ever received, and thanks also for extra info I do really think will need

Comment: @MadProgrammer (-: I know that you answering most of answers here, probably two weeks off can help you with it, and most of answers are/then will be without answers:-) and with pack(), them best place for the location, last one should be about visible, please